# Apache HTTP Server Location directive - exclude url

Tags: apache, https, proxy, location

I've an Apache HTTP server that is used as a proxy (over https) for JBoss-deployed webapp. I've the following entry in a conf file:

```
<Location "/app">
    ProxyPass           http://localhost:8080/app
    ProxyPassReverse    http://localhost:8080/app
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Private Documentation Repository"
    AuthUserFile <path-to-file>
    Require valid-user
</Location>
```

As You can see, a valid user is required to access /app.
The question is: how to write a directive that will exclude one particular file from JBoss webapp, so that access to this file won't require a valid user e.g.:

```
<Location "/app/some-file.xyz">
    ProxyPass           http://localhost:8080/app/some-file.xyz
    ProxyPassReverse    http://localhost:8080/app/some-file.xyz
</Location>
```

I mean: when user requests anything (app/) but /app/some-file.xyz he/she will be prompted for the password, otherwise Apache will enable the user to download some-file.xyz. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<Location "/app/*.xyz">
    allow from all 
    satisfy any 
    ProxyPass           http://localhost:8080/app/*.xyz
    ProxyPassReverse    http://localhost:8080/app/*.xyz
</Location>
```